# Fourier Transform of t/(t^2+1)^2

Tags: fourier-transform

Can you help me with what steps to follow to find the Fourier transform of t/(t^2+1)^2. I know it will be solved on the lines of time-frequency duality but cannot seem to get the exact steps for it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform+t%2F%28t%5E2%2B1%29%5E2

Comment: Better to ask this question on Math SE